# Goal-testing when node is "Generated" vs when node is "Expanded" contradiction (breadth-first search)

Tags: breadth-first-search

In my textbook "AI: A Modern Approach" it states that we **expand** a node to **generate** it's children.
So I understand the definition of those two words as:

Expand - Generate/create all the new children nodes of a particular node

Generating - A (child) node is generated when its parent is expanded

Now, when it comes to goal testing (specifically breadth first search in this case), my textbook states that "the goal test is applied to each node when it is **generated** rather than when it is **selected for expansion**". However, tutorial videos I have watched online seem to do the goal-test only when they select a node for expansion. Two short example videos are below:

[Breadth First Search - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wu2sojwsyQ)

[Breadth-First Search Algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0mSyyFE2M)

In both videos they expand all the nodes at a certain depth therefore generating all the children of the new depth, then only when they traverse those new children and find one of them as a goal node do they stop, so they do the goal-test only when they select that new child node for expansion.

From my understanding of the goal test definition above (let's use video 1 as an example), once the gentleman has expanded A and generates the new children B and G1 then he should stop because he should have run the goal test immediately on both B and G1 upon expanding A and then come to the conclusion that G1 is a goal node.

Am I understanding this correctly? Are those videos just incorrect?

This is really throwing me off since I can't seem to find a concise explanation.

Thank you